# Using jQuery To Animate Inserting Text Into Div

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Is it possible with jQuery to use `animate`, to fill a div with content smoothly, i.e. animate the height of the div growling larger as I insert content?

For example (HTML):

```
 <div id="my-div"></div>
```

Then (JavaScript):

```
 $("#my-div").html("some new really long string of text which makes the div height increase.");
```

I would like to animate the insert of the html, and thus the height increase.

Comment: Slidedown is possible, but i like a FadeIn very much for something like this.

Comment: @Justin I edited my answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to truly animate the text in, you would have to slowly append the text, one letter at a time.  You can get a similar effect by using what others have mentioned already, .slideDown()

http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/fCAVp/

```
$("#my-div")
    .hide()
    .html("some new really long string of text ...")
    .slideDown('slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `slideDown()` and `slideUp()`.

something like this:

```
$("#my-div").slideUp('slow', function() { $("#my-div").html("some new really long string of text which makes the div height increase."); }).slideDown('slow');
```

**Edit:**

you may want to increase the div height smoothly, to do so you can use `animate()` and `height()` [`this way`](http://jsfiddle.net/MGrrR/).

I also created a [`FadeIn sample`](http://jsfiddle.net/auesz/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a combination of the css attributes `overflow:hidden; height:...` and jQuery's [slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) function.

Insert the text into a fixed-height div, determine the new height and animate it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple: adjust the height automatically and very slowly as you drop more text in the div:

```
$('#thedivid').append('<p>'+newtextbeingadded+'</p>').animate( { 'height':'auto' },5000 );
```

That should, probably, do the trick. You might need to adjust the 5000 accordingly.

Also, chances are that a vertical scroll bar would appear so you would want to make the 'thedivid' with overflow:hidden;

Good luck!